# PHP session won't unset array item when specified to so

Tags: php, ajax, session, foreach, unset

I have some AJAX code that gets the "remove" button and sends it to `rem_cart.php`

```
 $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){

                            var product_id = $(this).attr('id');
                            var action = "Delete";
                            console.log(product_id);

                            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove 
                            this product from your cart?")) {

                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "../PHP_Scripts/rem_cart.php",
                                    method: "POST",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    data: {

                                    product_id: product_id,
                                    action: action

                                    },

                                    success:function(data){
                                    $('#order_table').html(data.order_table);
                                    $('.badge').text(data.cart_item);
                                }
                              });

                            }else{
                                return false;
                            }

                        });
```

Here is the `rem_cart.php`:

```
if (isset($_POST['action'] == "Delete")) {
     foreach ($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['product_id'] == $_POST['product_id']) {
             unset($_SESSION['shoppingcart'][$key]);

        }
     }
}
```

The session key does not unset.

The network tab shows all the correct info as well:

```
product_id: 12
action: Delete
```

Can somebody shed some light?

Comment: `session_start()` ??? And what is `$_POST['product_id']` is it JSON that needs `json_decode()`?

Comment: Sounds like session_start problem

Comment: @AbraCadaver sesion_start() is at the top of every page.

Comment: @AbraCadaver where would i put json_decode()?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` to see what is there.